# Selenium Chromedriver not working in Microsoft Fabric

Tags: azure, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web scrapping script that uses selenium chromedriver in jupyter notebook to scrap some online data for a weekly report that is issued for our company.

I am trying to migrate this script to Microsoft Fabric so it can be automated but I am having issues with selenium and I can't figure out what I need to do.

The selenium version I am using is 4.11.2.

I have included the code I used for jupyter notebook below. If anyone has any info/tips on what I need to do to get this working in fabric I would really appreciate it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import os 
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Creating a webdriver instance
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--incognito")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    driver.get(url)
   
    driver.maximize_window()
```

I have tried downloading the chromedriver exe file - saving that to the fabric lakehouse and referencing that exe file in the executable_path variable but I got a 'permission denied' error - which doesnt make sense as I am currently the only person who has access to the workspace.
Also the Fabric environment doesn't seem to allow exe files to be loaded to the environment so not sure what the alternative is.

[image: Microsoft Fabric Environment]